# HowTo secure Flash policy server?

Tags: flash, ssl, policy

I have a simple c++ policy server listening on port 843 in order to respond back to flash programs my crossdomain.xml security policy file.

Everything works perfectly until I added support for SSL.

Now when I open a connection from an SWF file using SecureSocket my c++ policy server is never called on port 843. I thought I might have a problem with the firewall so I disabled it but again if I use SecureSocket instead of XMLSocket my c++ is never called.

Any help? Has anyone managed to receive  when using a secure socket from flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

policy.xml file for SecureSocket must be send over TLS/SSL connection as well